# Consulta agrupada MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde constam os campos:

- cod_paciente
- cod_patologia
- principal

um paciente pode ter mais de uma patologia, porem uma deve ser definida como principal, preciso filtrar quais os pacientes não possuem nenhum item definido como principal.

tentei o seguinte, sem sucesso.

```
select cod_cli,
    count(CASE 
            WHEN principal IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS cont_principal
from cid_cli group by cod_cli
```

conseguem me sugerir algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola,

Acredito que você precisa usar a clasula having (que é o filtro do group by)

```
select cod_paciente from tabela group by cod_paciente having count(principal) < 1
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!